# Capture media without user input in Codenameone

Tags: codenameone

Is it possibly to capture media - pictures and video automatically without showing th media capture interface and without taking any user input. We want to build an app to tae snapshots and record short audio without the user input as part of a taxi driver app.

Answer (score 1):

There will be some interaction such as permission prompts which are inevitable. I'm not sure if the native OS's will allow video/image capture without a preview but if they will you can probably use https://github.com/codenameone/CameraKitCodenameOne or base your solution on the work we did there.

Audio is easier. We have the `MediaManager` API which supports audio capture. You can use that to record anything.

Comment: Maybe I will just do video streaming.